# String comparison in Java: what is wrong with "=="?

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

```
public class S_eaqual {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "one", s2 = "two";
        if (s1 + s2 == "onetwo") {
            System.out.println("Yes..equal");
        }
    }
}
```

This type of comparison shows errors. Is this not the right way of comparing strings?
Two `String` objects can be compared using `==` operator. So why this is showing error?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Comment: I tried executing it. I didnt get any error. It just didn't print anything bcos the strings are not equal. Can you tell us the error that you got?

Answer (score 4):

String should be compared using `equals` method.

```
String s1 = "one", s2 = "two";
if("onetwo".equals(s1+s2)) {
  System.out.println("Yes..equal");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
String s3 = s1 + s2
if(s3.equals("onetwo")) {
...
```

`==` compares if they refer to the same object, and the result of `s1+s2` isn't in this case, and the `.equals()` method on string compares that the values are the same. In general, you only use `==` for primitive value comparisons. Although you can do it for objects iff you intend to check to make sure that two references point to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

use `(s1+s2).equals("onetwo");` instead

Answer (score 2):

Use *equals*:

```
if (s1.concat(s2).equals("onetwo")) System.out.println("Yes..equal");
```